# Error building GEOS on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, geodjango, geos

Following the directions to install [geodjango on linux ubuntu 18.04](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/), so far here are my commands:

```
sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin

wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2

tar xjf geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2

sudo apt-get install build-essential

cd geos-3.4.2

./configure

make
```

I get this error

```
In file included from ../../../include/geos/geom/Geometry.h:25:0,
                 from IndexedPointInAreaLocator.cpp:17:
../../../include/geos/platform.h:112:2: error: #error "Can not compile without isnan function or macro"
 #error "Can not compile without isnan function or macro"
  ^~~~~
In file included from ../../../include/geos/geom/Coordinate.h:158:0,
                 from ../../../include/geos/geom/Envelope.h:25,
                 from ../../../include/geos/geom/Geometry.h:27,
                 from IndexedPointInAreaLocator.cpp:17:
../../../include/geos/geom/Coordinate.inl: In member function ‘bool geos::geom::Coordinate::isNull() const’:
../../../include/geos/geom/Coordinate.inl:38:10: error: ‘ISNAN’ was not declared in this scope
  return (ISNAN(x) && ISNAN(y) && ISNAN(z));
          ^~~~~
../../../include/geos/geom/Coordinate.inl:38:10: note: suggested alternative: ‘SNAN’
  return (ISNAN(x) && ISNAN(y) && ISNAN(z));
          ^~~~~
          SNAN
../../../include/geos/geom/Coordinate.inl: In member function ‘bool geos::geom::Coordinate::equals3D(const geos::geom::Coordinate&) const’:
../../../include/geos/geom/Coordinate.inl:77:21: error: ‘ISNAN’ was not declared in this scope
   ((z == other.z)||(ISNAN(z) && ISNAN(other.z)));
                     ^~~~~
../../../include/geos/geom/Coordinate.inl:77:21: note: suggested alternative: ‘SNAN’
   ((z == other.z)||(ISNAN(z) && ISNAN(other.z)));
                     ^~~~~
                     SNAN
Makefile:372: recipe for target 'IndexedPointInAreaLocator.lo' failed
make[5]: *** [IndexedPointInAreaLocator.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/ralph/geos-3.4.2/src/algorithm/locate'
Makefile:391: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[4]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/ralph/geos-3.4.2/src/algorithm/locate'
Makefile:445: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ralph/geos-3.4.2/src/algorithm'
Makefile:476: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ralph/geos-3.4.2/src'
Makefile:367: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ralph/geos-3.4.2'
Makefile:677: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

so following the docs does not seem to be working...

I do not know how to work around this error, any suggestions

are there any good write ups on how to install geos on ubuntu?

Comment: Are you required to use an older version of GEOS?  Not sure at which version exactly but ISNAN was moved into the standard namespace and this [commit](https://git.osgeo.org/gitea/geos/geos/commit/b4dff0b59f9116bcb0636dc65cb16196262d7ad0) accounted for it at somepoint in v3.4.  If you are using the latest version of g++ with old headers, it could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most definitely a problem with the preprocessor not finding a function in platform.h.  I might have an answer to the problem.

The ISNAN macro/function was moved to into the standard namespace when using cmath.h instead of math.h.  [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128899/is-isnan-in-the-std-namespace-more-in-general-when-is-std-necessary-optio)

This [commit](https://git.osgeo.org/gitea/geos/geos/commit/b4dff0b59f9116bcb0636dc65cb16196262d7ad0) allowed the preprocessor to find the right function for the macro definition.  This is the result of this [issue](https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ticket/784).

I am not certain when this change was deployed but there is a work around in the notes for the issue.  You need to explicitly tell g++ to use the '98 standard at configure time.

> Work-around by setting:
>
> `export CXX="g++ -std=c++98"`
>
> before running ./configure (without the patch, from the release tarball).

This is valid assuming you are using the newest GCC/G++ and using the older library as you have described.  If you can, use the newest library version as tinylyx has described that seemingly builds correctly.

Comment: so run this command `CXX="g++ -std=c++98"` after I unzip geos?

Comment: Before or after.  You are simply setting environment variables in the shell.  Be sure to use the `export` keyword, otherwise it will not take.  Hopefully, this is all you'll need.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version seems (both 3.6.2 and 3.7.0beta1) to work for me with gcc7.x .

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.7.0beta1.tar.bz2
tar xf geos-3.7.0beta1.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.7.0beta1/
./configure && make
```

Maybe you can find a newer version that works in http://download.osgeo.org/geos/

(tested with:

```
$g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
```

)

Comment: will this version work okay for uses in geodjango?

Comment: @ziggy from the page you linked, 3.6 should be supported.