# Cannot create PostGIS extension with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ubuntu, linux

I am a few days new to Linux Ubuntu and am in the process of setting up a PostGIS database to use in GeoDjango.

I am going to post all my commands that I have done so far

these are installed in order:

```
-------------------------------postgres------------------------
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev pgadmin4

sudo apt-get install postgis

-------------------------------geodjango------------------------

sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install gcc g++ clang make

--geos
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
tar xjf geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.4.2
export CXX="g++ -std=c++98"
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..

--proj 4
wget http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-4.9.1.tar.gz
wget http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-datumgrid-1.5.tar.gz
tar xzf proj-4.9.1.tar.gz
cd proj-4.9.1/nad
tar xzf ../../proj-datumgrid-1.5.tar.gz
cd ..
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..

--gdal
wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.2.0/gdal-2.2.0.tar.gz
tar xzf gdal-2.2.0.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.2.0
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

now when I go into pgAdmin 4 and run `create extension postgis` i get this error

```
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/postgis-2.4.so": /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.4.so.0: undefined symbol: GEOSVoronoiDiagram
SQL state: XX000
```

**UPDATE**

followed the directions in this link https://kitcharoenp.github.io/postgresql/postgis/2018/05/28/set_up_postgreSQL_postgis.html and still got the same error

Comment: I used this method - https://kitcharoenp.github.io/postgresql/postgis/2018/05/28/set_up_postgreSQL_postgis.html I think you need to replace lsb_release with boinic > example: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg main

Comment: can you spell it out for me. like what exact command do I need to run? do I need to uninstall postgres and reinstall?

Comment: reinstalled and got the same error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message points to GEOS,

> ERROR:  could not load library
>   "/usr/lib/postgresql/10/lib/postgis-2.4.so":
>   /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.4.so.0: undefined symbol: GEOSVoronoiDiagram

You might have better luck with installing a more recent version of GEOS (see e.g. [Error building GEOS on Ubuntu 18.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289409)):

Replace 3.4.2 with 3.6.2 in:

```
--geos
wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
tar xjf geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.4.2
export CXX="g++ -std=c++98"
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

-- Update --

With new versions of GEOS, you also don't need the CXX flag, which forces (a quite) old C++ standard. When possible, I'd try to compile the libraries with the same compiler and settings with PostgreSQL.

Comment: okay, does it matter which one I install first?

Comment: @ziggy I updated the answer, just realizing that you are not compiling PostGIS. But if you are, you can specify which geos version to use:  gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253202

Comment: okay I uninstalled 3.4.2 and reinstalled 3.6.2 and it worked, thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you are in Ubuntu, you can install it from packages!

Instead of compiling them from source, you can just execute this command and all the required packages will be installed.

```
sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
```

Here is a complete example on how to set up a database with PostGIS on Ubuntu 18, PostgreSQL 10

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y binutils postgresql postgresql-contrib
# Password for the database
$ sudo su - postgres
$ psql
> CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
> CREATE DATABASE myproject OWNER myprojectuser;
> ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
> ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
> ALTER ROLE myprojectuser SET timezone TO 'UTC';
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myproject TO myprojectuser;
# Test conection, quit with \q or ctrl+d
$ psql -h localhost -U myprojectuser myproject

# Install 
$ sudo apt-get install binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin 
# Check package version, searching with command
# sudo apt-cache search postgresql | grep gis
$ sudo apt-get install -y postgis postgresql-10-postgis-2.4 python-psycopg2
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION postgis; CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;" myproject
```

Reference: [Installing Geospatial libraries: GDAL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#gdalbuild)